# Asp.net Core OpenIdConnect (OIDC) Where to Validate State Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, openid-connect, auth0, asp.net-core-2.2

Where is the suggested place to validate the state parameter in the OIDC middleware and possibly reject the request?

```
OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (RedirectContext context) =>
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.State = "ENCODED_STATE_PARAMETER";
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Thanks,
Ruben

Comment: I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 3):

After digging around the OIDC source I found this solution,

```
options = new OpenIdConnectOptions()
// ...
options.ProtocolValidator = new MyOIDCProtocalValidator();

public sealed class MyOIDCProtocalValidator: OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator
{
    public MyOIDCProtocalValidator(): base()
    {
        // not sure if these are needed
        base.RequireState = true;
        base.RequireStateValidation = true;
    }

    protected override void ValidateState(OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // validate state here 
        // if(valid) do nothing
        // else throw new OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidStateException();
    }
}
```